How to properly configure pytest to perform a set of actions before and after all my tests
I want to properly test my FastAPI application. The app uses a local postgres db with an async connection and alembic to do migrations which works fine.
Now I want to properly unit test my application with a real postgres test db. So basically I want to achieve the following:

Connect to my postgres db
Create a new database called test_db
Run alembic migrations to get the same schema and initial data as my real db
Run all unit tests now
Run alembic downgrade base to drop all tables and delete the data
Delete the database test_db

The problem is that when I run pytest to execute the unit tests my test will run but no db is being created. So effectively only step 4 runs. But nothing else.
I have the following structure in my tests dir:
.
└── tests/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test_app.py
    └── test_user.py

I created a conftest.py that includes the code for step 1-3 and 5-6:
import pytest
import asyncpg
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, create_async_engine
# from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
from alembic.config import Config
from alembic import command
from config import config

TEST_DATABASE_URI = config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI_UNIT_TEST

# 1. Create the test database
async def create_test_db():
    print("Creating test database")
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(
        user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASSWD, database=config.DB_NAME, host=config.DB_HOST
    )
    try:
        await conn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {config.DB_NAME}_test;")
        print("Database created successfully")
    except asyncpg.exceptions.DuplicateDatabaseError as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        await conn.close()

# 2. Drop the test database
async def drop_test_db():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(
        user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASSWD, database=config.DB_NAME, host=config.DB_HOST
    )
    try:
        await conn.execute(f"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {config.DB_NAME}_test;")
    finally:
        await conn.close()


# 3. Run Alembic migrations
def run_migrations(db_uri, direction="upgrade", revision="head"):
    alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
    alembic_cfg.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", db_uri)
    if direction == "upgrade":
        command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, revision)
    elif direction == "downgrade":
        command.downgrade(alembic_cfg, revision)


# 4. Fixture to manage the test database lifecycle
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def setup_test_db():
    print("Hello world")
    # Create test database
    await drop_test_db()
    await create_test_db()

    # Run migrations
    run_migrations(TEST_DATABASE_URI, "upgrade", "head")

    yield  # All tests execute here

    # Clean up: Downgrade and drop test database
    run_migrations(TEST_DATABASE_URI, "downgrade", "base")
    drop_test_db()


# 5. Fixture for async test engine
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def async_test_engine():
    engine = create_async_engine(url=TEST_DATABASE_URI, echo=False)
    yield engine
    await engine.dispose()


My test_app.py looks like this:
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from httpx import AsyncClient
from httpx._transports.asgi import ASGITransport
from app import app 
from config import config


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_test_db")  # Ensure setup_test_db fixture is used
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_root_route():
    # Use ASGITransport explicitly
    transport = ASGITransport(app=app)
    async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="http://test") as client:
        # Perform GET request
        response = await client.get("/")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.json() == {"message": config.WELCOME_MESSAGE}

The idea would be that when a pytest session starts (running the unit tests) it should first setup my test_db, then run all the unit test using that test_db and delete the test_db again. However the function setup_test_db() is never triggered. The "Hello World" statement is never printed in the terminal and the db did not perform any read/write operations during that time.
How can I set this up correctly so that:

The test_db is setup once at the beginning of the session
The routes called within the unit test actually use the test_db session instead of the real prod session

Or is there a better or simpler way to achieve this than what I am planning to do right now?

Async fixtures do not work out of the box. You need to install helper packages, such as anyio or pytest-asyncio. and mark your fixture as requiring async semantics.
Example
import asyncio

import pytest
import pytest_asyncio

# NB. Use pytest_asyncio.fixture NOT pytest.fixture
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='session', loop_scope='session')
async def my_fixture():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    yield 'foo'

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_foo(my_fixture):
   assert my_fixture == 'foo'

Here I've merged conftest.py and your test file, but that doesn't make a difference. conftest.py is just common place to shared fixtures.

I tried this but: Like my previous version the code in conftest.py is not executed at all and I also get this warning: tests\conftest.py:50   C:\Users\myUser\my-project\backend-v2\tests\conftest.py:50: PytestRemovedIn9Warning: Marks applied to fixtures have no effect   See docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#applying-a-mark-to-a-fixture-function     @pytest.mark.asyncio

My bad, I forgot you had to change how you set the fixture for pytest-asyncio.
